# Bitbucket commits from other author not pulling

Tags: bitbucket

I have created a private repository in bitbucket for a project on my own.
The other day I was showing it to some coworkers and I made a commit from another computer, which was saved remotely with another author.
Back at home, I made a pull and I got the error 'Nothing to fetch', nor can I upload changes because there are changes in remote that needed to be downloaded, so the branch has become unusable.

I'm working on eclipse in both cases.

Timeline:

- Computer 1, user 1 (owner of repo)

  > Create project
  >   Made serveral commits.
- Computer 2

  > Checkout project
  >   Made some changes.
  >   Push to remote, (without realizing that the author was another, configured     in eclipse for other unrelated projects).
- Back to computer 1:

  > Pull: I get an alert message. Operation cancelled: Nothing to fetch.

Tried: Approve the commit, add that second author in the username alias list.

Also tried to unlock the situation by having the last commit go with the correct user. So now the branch history looks like this:

- 643480f Author User1 - Commiter User1
- 02d5072 Author User2 - Commiter User2
- 81e65a0 Author User1 - Commiter User1
- 7f6fe95 Author User1 - Commiter User1
- 071cbb7 Author User1 - Commiter User1

**Ammend try steps:**

- git status

> In the branch development Your branch is up to date with 'origin /
>   development'. There is nothing to commit, work directory clean

- git checkout 02d507219b83053aa0de58f9f12b82a71de3e638

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout. If you want to create a new branch to retain commits
>   you create, you may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout
>   command again. Example: git checkout -b  HEAD is now
>   02d5072... Changes in DB structure:

- git commit --amend --author="User1 "

> [HEAD detached a970307] Changes in DB structure:  User1
>   "owner.user@gmail.com"  Date: Wed Nov 6 08:39:32 2019 +0100  2 files
>   changed, 54 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

- git push origin development

> Everything up-to-date

Comment: Did you push your commit from another computer? Can you please share the error that you get at time of pull or push?

Comment: I edited the question. I get a simple alert. Not much more. Surely there is an underlying error that is not being shown to me.

Comment: Did you take pull before push from computer 2? Dose commit made in computer 1 is visible in bitbuket repo?

Comment: I bitbucket web, all is visible and all fits. Before push from computer 2 i made a checkout, that is like a pull. I could not commit if not up to date.

Comment: Checkout is not like pull. Checkout will just revert back your changes and get you back to your previous file state. you will have to take before making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can amend the author name from other computer where the commit was initially pushed from using the below command.

```
git commit --amend --author="Your name"
```

Once updated, then you can push the changes to the remote repository.

Comment: I've been looking and i don't know if ammend works when the commit is not the last. Because I tried to unlock the situation by having the last commit go with the correct user. I edit the question with that fact.

Comment: amend can work perfectly with commits which you have committed.

Comment: Since the commit to be amended is not the last one, I've made a checkout to the commit to amend and executed the command. It's now ok in local repo. How do I proceed from here to push?

Comment: If local repo has been updated, then just push it to remote. Are you getting any error performing a push ?

Comment: Not a problem but i lose the amend changes when back to the head. Steps:
- Checkout to the commit to amend (from eclipse)
- git status from console: Detached head to 02d5072 ... ok
- git commit --amend --author="Your name"
- Back to eclipse: I see the author changed ... ok
- git push origin development --> Everything up-to-date
- Back to the HEAD of the branch in eclipse: the author is the wrong again.
I think nothing is actually commited.

Comment: Can you share the git output in the question itself as an update ?

Comment: Question updated with the steps i've followed and the console output.
After all that commands, i can see the correct author in the eclipse history tab (the commiter remains with the wrong user, i assume that cannot be changed).
But nothing has been pushed to remote, and if i try to return to HEAD, I return to the initial situation.

Comment: Please use `git reset --soft "commit/target"`instead of `git checkout`.